# Data comes to the table as undefined when using SignalR [SOLVED]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I am developing a project with ASP.NET Core. In this project, I want to retrieve data using the SignalR library, but the data comes to the table as "undefined".

I am using PostgreSQL and N-Tier Architecture.

tasklisthub.js side code;

```js
"use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/taskListHub").build();

$(function () {
    connection.start().then(function () {
        alert('Connected to SignalR');
        InvokeTaskList();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return console.error(error.toString());
    });
});

function InvokeTaskList() {
    connection.invoke("SendTaskList").catch(function (error) {
        return console.error(error.toString());
    })
}

connection.on("ReceivedTaskList", function (taskList) {
    GetTaskList(taskList);
});

function GetTaskList(taskList) {
    $('#getTaskList tbody').empty();

    var tablerow;
    $.each(taskList, function (index, value) {
        tablerow = $('<tr/>');
        tablerow.append(`<td>${value.CreateUser}</td>`);
        tablerow.append(`<td>${value.TaskTitle}</td>`);
        tablerow.append(`<td>${value.Priority}</td>`);
        tablerow.append(`<td>${value.CreateDate}</td>`);
        tablerow.append(`<td>${value.Status}</td>`);
        $('#getTaskList').append(tablerow);
    });
}
```

TaskListHub.cs side code;

```cs
public class TaskListHub : Hub
    {
        TaskListManager taskListManager = new TaskListManager(new EFTaskListDataAccessLayer());

        public TaskListHub(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }

        public async Task SendTaskList()
        {
            var taskList = taskListManager.itemGetList();
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivedTaskList", taskList);
        }
    }
```

appsettings.json side code;

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "User ID=postgres;Password=ada;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=pmts;Pooling=true;"
  }
```

[image: The data coming to the table is as in the picture]

Comment: Have you debug in your browser to check the value of `taskList`?  Maybe you can console.log(taskList) to check the value first.

Comment: Very interesting, the column title is "TaskTitle" but in the console it appears as "taskTitle".

When I typed `${value.taskTitle}`, the data came.

Thanks.